# PHP Persist variable across all requests

Tags: php, lamp

In some languages C# or .NET this would be a static variable, but in PHP the memory is cleared after each request. I want the value to persist across all requests. I don't wan't $_SESSION because that is different for each user.

**To help explain here is an example:**
I want to have a script like this that will count up. No matter which user/browser opens the url.

```
<?php
function getServerVar($name){
    ...
}
function setServerVar($name,$val){
    ...
}
$count = getServerVar("count");
$count++;
setServerVar("count", $count);
echo $count;
```

I want the value stored in memory. It will not be something that needs to persist when apache restarts and the data is not that important that it needs to be thread safe.

**UPDATE**: I'm fine if it holds different values per server in a loadbalanced environment. Static variables in C# or Java will not be in sync either.

Comment: You're going to want to use something like redis or memcached. This will store whatever you want server side and can be accessed by all users.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947595/php-session-like-storage-global-across-all-users

Comment: It looks like what I want is shm_get_var, shm_set_var from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947595/php-session-like-storage-global-across-all-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically use a database to store the count.

However as an alternative you could do so using a file:

```
<?php
$file = 'count.txt';
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    touch($file);
}

//Open the File Stream
$handle = fopen($file, "r+");

//Lock File, error if unable to lock
if(flock($handle, LOCK_EX)) {
    $size = filesize($file);
    $count = $size === 0 ? 0 : fread($handle, $size); //Get Current Hit Count
    $count = $count + 1; //Increment Hit Count by 1
    echo $count;
    ftruncate($handle, 0); //Truncate the file to 0
    rewind($handle); //Set write pointer to beginning of file
    fwrite($handle, $count); //Write the new Hit Count
    flock($handle, LOCK_UN); //Unlock File
} else {
    echo "Could not Lock File!";
}

//Close Stream
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Could also use sqlite if you're going to be using a file anyway.

Comment: @Mike coulda shoulda woulda

Answer (score 2):

In php your going to have to use an external store that all servers share. The most commonly used tool is memcached, but sql and redis both work fine for this use case.

Comment: The only sensible answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is, like bspates said, a tool that does not depend on any resource on your server. If you have various servers, you cannot rely on memory-based mechanisms on each machine.
You have to store this number outside the servers, because each server will store the value for its own file or memory.

File writting, like $_SESSION, will work if you have only one server to receive your requests. For more than one server, you need any type of database where all your servers will communicate with.

Answer (score -1):

One of the simplest ways is to change `SESSION`'s behavior, although you couldn't have regular sessions anymore.

All you have to do is to add the below code before `session_start()`. This code makes `session_id` the same for all requests and therefore assumes all of them being in one session (even if you change it from the browser's Storage tab, server still sends the below code):

```
session_id('fq8aapoka3331'); // Or any other random and fixed phrase
```

**IMPORTANT: You have to do some work in order to increase sessions duration such as changing `lifetime` with `session_set_cookie_params`, and changing `session.save_path` (in shared hostings) and `session.gc_maxlifetime` with `ini_set`**

Comment: That's a horrible solution that will halt the site due to session lock.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks but isn't there any way to prevent sessions from being locked in this solution?

Comment: No, session file is locked by default. For a single user is's OK, but if all users will use the same session, the timeout will grow as a snowball