# PHP global variable persistent across requests

Tags: php, performance, global-variables

**I need a global variable to be persistent across requests**

I'm aware of a similar question [PHP Persist variable across all requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984067/php-persist-variable-across-all-requests) but I'm concerned about what solution performs better because **as the variable is `global` it must be set for every request.**

So far the solutions that I can think of are

**1. storing the value to the database.**

But every request have one more hit on the db.

**2. storing the value into a file**

But every request hits the filesystem.
On *nix systems the disk access is cached so further reading should be from RAM and thus not hitting the drive.

**3. storing the value into a php include file and including that file at the main entry point of the web app.**

The file instead of the raw value of the variable would contain a `define`

`define("THE_GLOBAL", "ABC");`

Same concerns of (2) plus as php cache is active it may happen that the value isn't actually updated until the cache has a refresh.

**4. using nosql like *redis***

I don't like to set up redis just for that. Plus the variable have to be persistent across restarts of the web application or reboots of the system.
And implementing this would require extra work.

---

I think the best solution is **(2)**. But maybe I'm wrong.

Any indication or suggestion supported by valid arguments would be very welcome.

Comment: $_SESSION is per-session "global" backed by some persistent store.. not GLOBAL though. (But honestly, you don't have a performance problem until you do .. which you don't.)

Comment: What is the nature of this variable... whats it used for? Is it changed via some admin interface running in the browser or is it more like a configuration value? It sounds like "configuration" and this I would say **2** is the way to go.

Comment: @prodigitalson it is a configuration value and now it's just set with a `define` (so it's a constant). But I'd like to make it editable via the admin interface. Now when I want to change it I need to edit the code. More specifically the variable is called `READ_ONLY` and is normally `false`, indicating the web app accepts updates/inserts both on the db and filesystem. During *maintenance* or in some other rare occassions I need to set it temporarily to `true` and switch back to `false` when I'm done.

Comment: Then yeah id go with the file setup. That said i dont generally like free floating constants, especially for something like this. I much prefer a class instance the holds configuration values injected into the things that need. Though it sounds like doing that would be way out of scope for where you are at on the project now :-)

Comment: Well then in a case like this I tend to fork my configuration between a file and the database. Usually the only config that gets stored in a file are truly static values, and what's necessary to get to the point of having a DB handle initialized, then the rest in a config table. Really you're either looking at 'another hit on the database' or standing up another persistent store like Redis. Using a file is still an option, but the least attractive by far for something you want to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use **3**:

- Including a php files is more *"elegant"* than reading a text file (which both are btw)
- The php file will be both cached by *nix filesystem and php opcode cache
- You'll have no issues with opcode cache because when you'll edit the file through your administration backend the file will have a new date... therefore opcode will be *"compiled"* again

If you are still concerned you can use a specific function to invalidate a single file from the cache. If you use the PHP built-in opcache you might use `opcache_invalidate` ([this is the reference from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-invalidate.php)) before changing the value in the file. `opcache_invalidate` requires **PHP >= 5.5.0** btw.

Comment: I like the suggestion to solve #3 issues by invalidating the cache. Including a php file is elegant, writing a PHP file upon update is not elegant so I don't agree with the first statement. Thank you. +1

Comment: You both are elegant people, imho.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Simone Conti answer, I implemented a similar cache system based on php file generation. With the [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.serialize.php) and [addslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) functions, you can easily store every type of variables (objects, etc...)

Here is an exemple of the file (`maVar.php`) you have to generate :

```
<?php return unserialize("s:8:\"Ma Value\";") ; ?>
```

You can then get your var this way :

```
$myVar = include 'cache_folder/maVar.php' ;
```

And of course you can easily create 2 fonctions `setCachedVar($name, $value)` and `getCachedVar($name)` for greater convenience.